# Angular 5 + Node JS prevent caching on Heroku

Tags: angular, caching, heroku, browser-cache

I'm experiencing a problem with cache in my web application.

We were using AngularJS before, and now we migrated to Angular 5 and went live to production.

But whoever enters the web app, they say it is not loading. They can see the new pages, css etc, but it stucks some how. We suggest them to make Cmd+Shift+R and then it works.

I'm using Heroku server with NodeJS and Angular 5 as frontend.

What should I do to make it work without hard refresh?